# how to write a Query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.ms_expese and track_expense.Using this table generate a fact table
I want the expense_name in ms_expense,expense_amount from track_expense.

I want to get the sum of expense_amount for a particular expense_name based on date.The date in the order of 1,2...12 as month id

```
            SELECT DATE_Format(a.date,'%b') as month_id,b.expense_name AS  expense_type, sum(a.expense_amount) AS expense_amount FROM ms_expense b JOIN track_expense a on a.`expense_id`=b.`expense_id` group by DATE_Format(a.date,'%b')
```

how to put the month id in the order of 1,2,..12 and my date format y-m-d
I get the month in apr,aug and so on but i need jan as 1,feb as 2

I have 25 expenses(expense name).In this query i got the total expense amount of first expense only.I want the total expense of all expenses in every month

Comment: From clause is missing in SELECT query

Comment: Please show some sample data of those tables. Without, we have to guess what's in there.

Comment: Retrieve data in month basis.I get the total amount in january so monthid shows 1 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE fact AS 
(<your select query>)
```

Your select query can be in the following form

```
SELECT MONTH(date)as month_id,expense_name,sum(expense_amount) 
FROM ms_expense JOIN track_expense using (expense_id) 
group by expense_name,MONTH(date)
```

Comment: can you give the description of that two tables(ms_expense and track_expense)

Comment: Use Datepart:--

DATEPART(mm,date);

Comment: SELECT DATEPART(mm,date)as month_id,expense_name,sum(expense_amount) FROM ms_expense JOIN track_expense using (expense_id) group by expense_name,DATEPART(mm,date)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82187/discussion-between-arthi-and-amalamalpm).